# Where to modify the options Python is run with when using uWSGI?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, webserver, uwsgi

I'm using Python for my web server, which is Django, that communicates with my HTTP server over uWSGI. Where to modify the command line options Python is run with?

Comment: Exactly what options are you hoping to change?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Add `-u` option if it's not there already

Comment: You can change that by setting the PYTHONUNBUFFERED environment variable.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Alright. And how about `-bb` option?